# Dollar signs in an edef yield tex capacity exceeded

Tags: macros

I want my two dollars:

```
\documentclass{minimal}
\begin{document}
\edef\twodollars{\$2}
\end{document}
```

However, all I get is:

```
! TeX capacity exceeded, sorry [input stack size=5000].
\font@name ->
             \OT1/cmr/m/n/10 
l.3 \edef\twodollars{\$
                       2}
```

Is it possible to use `\edef` with a value that includes a dollar sign?

Comment: Why not just use `\def\twodollars{\$2}`?

Comment: @Werner: in the application the "2" is a macro \twoOrThree, and I want to use the value \twoOrThree has at the time of \twodollars definition, rather than the value at a later expansion of \twodollars.

Comment: Also, the dollar sign just has to look like a dollar sign when \twodollars is expanded in plain horizontal mode text.  I didn't see a "\textdollarsign" like for underscore.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use

```
\documentclass{minimal}
\begin{document}
\edef\twodollars{\string$2} \twodollars
\end{document}
```

`\string` changes the category code for `$` to `12` (other).

Comment: Works like a charm, even in the convoluted mess of my real application.  Thanks!

Comment: @JackSchmidt: If you need this more often, consider defining a macro for the dollar. For example, the `newverbs` package allows for `\Verbdef\dollar|$|`, which also works for other special characters including `%`, where `\string` does not work.

Answer (score 6):

The correct way is to say

```
\makeatletter
\protected@edef\twodollars{\$2}
\makeatother
```

as `\$` is defined via `\DeclareRobustCommand`. An alternative is to say

```
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\robustify\$
\edef\twodollars{\$2}
```